# React Route v4.1.1 for web not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I changed my original code to this now after few suggestions: 
I have this in my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import './index.css';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
    //path is where it should take you.
    //Component is it should take you after slash
    <Router>
        <Route path='/' component={App}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Now the error I get is: [Screenshot of my full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Tma.jpg)

I have also tried this:
 `import { BrowserHistory} from 'react-router-dom';`
There are many tutorials online for past versions but I could not find the one that actually worked for v4.1.1. Even their github training is outdated. 
I am basically trying to go to my login page when the user clicks on "Profile" in my navbar. 
I am really lost and any help would be appreciated as I just started learning React.

Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you have `<App />` in there? Get rid of that. Only have Routes.

Comment: Can you try the basic example provided here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include full code. Here it is: `import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import './index.css';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
    //path is where it should take you.
    //Component is it should take you after slash
    <Router>
        <Route path='/' component={App}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
` Sorry. It now says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported APP component. And BTW if you do not want to have two APP components in the view, get rid of `<App/>`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include full code. Here it is:                                         
 `import React from 'react'; import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; import App from './App'; import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'; import './index.css'; import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'; ReactDOM.render( //path is where it should take you. //Component is it should take you after slash <Router> <Route path='/' component={App}/> </Router>, document.getElementById('root') ); registerServiceWorker();`  
Sorry. It now says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined